# Sorted dict to list

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have this:

```
dictionary = { (month, year) : [int, int, int] }
```

I'd like to get a list of tuples/lists with the ordered data(by month and year):

```
#example info
list = [(8,2010,2,5,3),(1,2011,6,7,8)...]
```

I've tried several times but I can't get to a solution.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use as your identifier built-in names -- that's a horrible practice, without any advantages, and it *will* land you in some peculiar misbehavior eventually.  So I'm calling the result `thelist` (an arbitrary, anodyne, just fine identifier), **not** `list` (shadowing a built-in).

```
import operator

thelist = sorted((my + tuple(v) for my, v in dictionary.iteritems()),
                 key = operator.itemgetter(1, 0))
```

Comment: thanks for your help Alex, I really appreciate it.

I don't use the identifiers "dictionary" and "list" in my code, I used them for the example to be clear :). Looks like I failed.

Comment: @mfalcon, you're welcome! `dictionary` was and is just fine... it's `list` that, used as a user-chosen identifier, rings alarms bells for me (unfortunately, many built-in names, such as `set`, `file`, `tuple`, `sorted`, `type`, `super`, `unicode`, `property`, `range`, ..., **are** "attractive nuisances" in tempting the unwary to unsound shadowing, being also nice, common, attractive, descriptive English words -- so it's a frequent problem and anybody who often tries to help newbies grows very sensitive to it;-).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get the job done:

```
>>> d = { (8, 2010) : [2,5,3], (1, 2011) : [6,7,8], (6, 2010) : [11,12,13] }
>>> sorted((i for i in d.iteritems()), key=lambda x: (x[0][1], x[0][0]))
[((6, 2010), [11, 12, 13]), ((8, 2010), [2, 5, 3]), ((1, 2011), [6, 7, 8])]
```

(Assuming the lambda should sort first by year, then month.)

See Alex Martelli's better answer for how to use `itemgetter` to solve this problem.

Comment: This gives a more deeply indented list than the OP was asking for, while my A gives him exactly the list of plain tuples he gives as an example (and as a bonus avoids any need for `lambda`;-).

Comment: @Alex:  good point :-) I reference your answer in mine. Thanks, as always, for sharing your vast expertise.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very concise way of doing what you ask.

```
l = [(m, y) + tuple(d[(y, m)]) for y, m in sorted(d)]
```